# Delay in Form Redirection Right After Clicking Submit Button

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with a specific script, I have a form that performs an action with the "GET" method and I need to put a delay of 200ms before the form's action is executed.

Form:

```
<form action="#" method="GET" autocomplete="chrome-off" enctype="text/plain" id="form_cotation">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center text-secondary h2 mb-3">
            <b>Faça Sua Cotação Gratuita</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 ">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="destinyGroup" class="form-label">Qual seu destino</label>
                <select name="destinyGroup" id="destinyGroup" class="form-control ">
                    <option value="">Selecione seu destino</option>
                    <option value="1">Brasil</option>
                    <option value="2">América Latina (inclui México)</option>
                    <option value="4">Estados Unidos e Canadá</option>
                    <option value="3">Europa</option>
                    <option value="5">Ásia</option>
                    <option value="6">África</option>
                    <option value="7">Oceania</option>
                    <option value="8">Múltiplos destinos</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="form-label">Data da Viagem:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6  ">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="departure" name="departure" value="" placeholder="Embarque" autocomplete="chrome-off" data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd'>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 ">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="arrival" name="arrival" value="" placeholder="Chegada" autocomplete="chrome-off" data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 relative">
                <label for="ages" class="form-label">Idade do(s) passageiro(s):</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="ages" name="ages" value="Selecione as idades" readonly>

                <div class="w-100 selectAges">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body ">

                            <div class="row mt-2">
                                <div class="col-7 pt-2">
                                    <label class="text-info h5"><span
                                            class="text-primary"><b>0 a 40</b></span>
                                        anos</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-5 ages">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <button class="btn-down">-</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <input type="text" class="w-100 p-0 text-center" name="old0" value="0" readonly>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <button class="btn-up">+</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-2">
                                <div class="col-7 pt-2">
                                    <label class="text-info h5"><span
                                            class="text-primary"><b>41 a 64</b></span>
                                        anos</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-5 ages">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <button class="btn-down">-</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <input type="text" class="w-100 p-0 text-center" name="old1" value="0" readonly>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <button class="btn-up">+</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-2">
                                <div class="col-7 pt-2">
                                    <label class="text-info h5"><span
                                            class="text-primary"><b>65 a 75</b></span>
                                        anos</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-5 ages">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <button class="btn-down">-</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <input type="text" class="w-100 p-0 text-center" name="old2" value="0" readonly>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <button class="btn-up">+</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-2">
                                <div class="col-7 pt-2">
                                    <label class="text-info h5"><span
                                            class="text-primary"><b>76 a 99</b></span>
                                        anos</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-5 ages">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <button class="btn-down">-</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <input type="text" class="w-100 p-0 text-center" name="old3" value="0" readonly>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <button class="btn-up">+</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center mt-4">
                                <a type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-aplicar text-white save">
                                    <b>
                                        Aplicar
                                    </b>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 ">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Nome:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " name="name" value="nome" id="name">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="email" class="form-label">E-mail:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control " id="email" value="email" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="phone" class=" form-label">Telefone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" class="phone form-control " id="phone" value="telefone" id="phone">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 mt-3 mb-3 order-3">
            <button class="btn w-100 btn-cotation" id="submitbtnt" type="submit">Cotar agora! ››</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and script

```
let timeToWait = 200; 
let button = document.getElementById('submitbtnt');

setTimeout(() => {
    button.onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        location.href ='URL-AQUI'
    }
}, timeToWait);
```

I've tried in several ways but I'm not able to activate the delay with setTimeout()

In short, what I need is to leave a delay of 200ms before right after clicking the submit button

Comment: put setTimeout inside your button click function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `setTimeout` inside the onclick function, so the delay start right after users click the button

```
button.onclick = function(e) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        e.preventDefault();
        location.href ='URL-AQUI'

    }, timeToWait);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did as you indicated and it worked here.

Answer (score 1):

to prevent form submit ion you need to run `preventDefault()` on the submit event

```
const formCotation = document.getElementById('form_cotation');
formCotation.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    formCotation.submit()
  }, 200);
});
```